C# compiler does not accept null for a nullable generic type property
public class ClassA<TUid>
{
    public TUid? Uid { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA<Guid>
{
    public void Test()
    {
        ClassB dto = new ClassB();
        dto.Uid = null;
    }
}

C# compiler doesn't accept this C# code at the line: dto.Uid = null saying that

Cannot convert null to 'Guid' because it is a non-nullable value type

Isn't generic type TUid in ClassA substituted with Guid in ClassB so it should result in Guid? like this?
public Guid? Uid { get; set; }

If I declare ClassA as non-generic
public class ClassA
{
    public TUid? Uid { get; set; }
}

or pass generic parameter as Guid?
public class ClassB : ClassA<Guid?>

then dto.Uid = null doesn't cause any problem.
What is it about the parameter type inference rules that confuses the compiler in the first example?

Your Type is Guid not Nullable<Guid>. Try for example with where TUid: struct and see what happens.

This is because T? has different meaning depending if T is a reference type or a value type.
If T is a value type type, using T? actually wrap the variable in another struct - the Nullable<T> struct.
However, if T is a reference type, using T? is still the same reference type, only now you're telling the compiler that it can be null.
When the compiler sees T? and T is a struct, it lowers the code to Nullable<T> - however, if T is a class, it can't do that, because Nullable<T> can only accept structs as T.
When you're not using generic constraints, the default behavior is like using a class constraint - so
class C<T> 
{
    public T? Value {get;set;}
}

is lowered the same as
class C<T> where T : class
{
    public T? Value {get;set;}
}

to this:
[NullableContext(2)]
[Nullable(0)]
internal class C<T>
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private T <Value>k__BackingField;

    public T Value
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <Value>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <Value>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}

However, when you add the struct constraint,
this
class C<T> where T : struct
{
    public T? Value {get;set;}
}

is lowered to this:
internal class C<T> where T : struct
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private Nullable<T> <Value>k__BackingField;

    public Nullable<T> Value
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <Value>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <Value>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}

You can play around with it on SharpLab.IO

The ? qualifier in generics is ... fun. With a where T : struct constraint: yes, it means Nullable<T> - but you don't have that, which means that T? actually means "for the purposes of Nullable Reference Type (NRT) tracking, this type should be considered nullable", which kicks the compiler to suggest null tests for things like Uid.Whatever(), and impacts the allowed parameters and member assignments by the external caller if the T is a class or interface - for example, for ClassA<string> and TUid? Uid, it considers obj.Uid = null to be valid, where-as with TUid Uid: obj.Uid = null would cause a NRT warning.
If you intend this type to always be used with value-types: add where T : struct
If you intend this type to remain generic, but to use Guid? in this specific case, then use : ClassA<Guid?>.
Keep in mind that NRT support is a relatively recent addition, and mostly impacts the compiler. The actual runtime doesn't know a lot (if anything) about NRTs. Before NRTs, the T? syntax wasn't even legal without the where T : struct constraint, and this underlying reality is what you're actually working with.
